# SQL Server 2008 Windows Auth Login Error: The login is from an untrusted domain

Tags: sql-server

When attempting to connect to a SQL Server 2008 Instance using Management Studio, I get the following error:

> Login failed. The login is from an
>   untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

I can login using SQL Authentication without problem.  I've been getting this error all of a sudden.  I have Mixed Mode Authentication turned on.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Additional Info:
64-bit version of SQL
Enterprise Edition
On Windows 2003 Server

Comment: what is the windows login account used for connecting to the sql server?

Comment: its my domain account that i've been using since forever

Comment: any change recently like a password change? sometimes the credentials gets cached..

Comment: no changes recently.. the only thing happened was just a reboot of our servers..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue was caused by a down Active Directory Server, which of course could not authenticate the Windows account. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 50):

Another reason this might happen (just happened to me) ... is the user's password expires. I didn't realize this until I tried to remote into the actual server and was prompted to change my password.

Comment: Just had this issue. Surprisingly I was still able to connect to Analysis Server :O

Comment: Can confirm..this was causing the same problem for me as well. Updating the password instantly solved the connection issue!

Comment: Just happened for me (Win 10), whilst it wasn't that my password had expired, I had just changed it via 'Ctrl-Alt-Del'.  I restarted and it was fine again.  Extremely annoying, changing the password also affected Outlook and OneDrive's ability to function.

Comment: Thanks, Saved my life

Comment: Changed my password with Ctrl-Alt-Del, (Win10) and started getting this error. Restarting didn't solve it.

Comment: Crazy!! Thank you!

Answer (score 39):

For me, this happened when I edited a blank `drivers/etc/hosts` file, and added an entry for a local website, but neglected to add `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: Worked for me as well. Somehow I have had some entry in hosts file which should not be there (I did not put it there myself and do not remember installing any software that could do it). Removing it resolved the issue

Comment: For Windows you can uupdate this file doing this http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: You saved my day! Thank

Answer (score 19):

For anyone else who runs into this, I had this in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   customname
```

and I needed it to be this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost   customname
```

Answer (score 16):

> "The issue was caused by a down Active Directory Server, which of course could not authenticate the Windows account"

It is not "of course - because if AD is not available then Kerberos authentication falls back to NTLM (domain account credentials are cached locally, one can login with it even if AD/Kerberos is not available).  I guess that you have possibly 2 simultaneous conditions for this failure to happen:

- SQL Server is not local (on another machine)
- The trust is configured "Kerberos only"

or other specific security network/server/AD/machine configurations

Comment: I've also seen this issue with AD named servers on a local machine FWTW

Comment: So, what should I do if SQL server is not local ?

Comment: Where and how to change "trust" configuration, which is currently "Kerberos only" ?

Answer (score 11):

**Make sure you aren't connected to a VPN on another domain\user**. Or, conversely, make sure you *are* connected, if that is what is required.

Comment: Wow, would never have thought!! Thanks! (I was connected to company VPN on MBP, using SSMS on VMWare)

Comment: This helped in my case. I had to use the domain name in the VPN connection.

Comment: This was my problem.  I was about to leave it as an answer but found your's first.  It made perfect sense once I saw it.  thanks

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue for a server instance on my local machine and found that it was because I was pointing to 127.0.0.1 with something other than "localhost" in my hosts file. There are two ways to fix this issue in my case:

1. Clear the offending entry pointing to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file
2. use "localhost" instead of the other name that in the hosts file that points to 127.0.0.1

*This only worked for me when I was running the sql server instance on my local box and attempting to access it from the same machine.

Answer (score 5):

There is a setting on the jTDS driver called USENTLMV2 that is set to false by default. Setting this to 'true' in my db software (DBVisualizer) solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue on machine disabling the loopback check setting:

1. Edit the Windows registry: Start –> Run > Regedit
2. Navigate to: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
3. Add a DWORD value called “DisableLoopbackCheck”
4. Set this value to 1

Answer (score 3):

try using a different valid login [using RUNAS command](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/09/07/tip-use-runas-to-set-your-windows-auth-domain-for-database-connections.aspx)

```
runas /user:domain\user “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssmsee.exe” 

runas /user:domain\user “C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmc.exe /s \”C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\BINN\SQL Server Enterprise Manager.MSC\”" 

runas /user:domain\user isqlw
```

Comment: I tried this with another windows account on the same domain, and got the same error.

Comment: try to get the server and client event logs. i guess we need more details.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was because i did not add the account to have roles I wanted to use to the SQL Database itself.  And also due to a bad password attempts via copy paste problem locking account.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, completely out there answer from me.  I was getting this error from a development environment hosted on VM VirtualBox.  Three servers; SharePoint, SQL DB and Domain Controller.  The SharePoint server couldn't connect to the configuration database.  I could still connect via ODBC for Sql authentication using SA account but not Windows authentication.  But that user would happily log into SSMS on the sql server itself.  I got a better error message from ODBC too and also by checking the failed login messages on sql server:

```
select text from sys.messages where message_id = '18452' and language_id = 1033
```

Can't take credit for this because I asked one of our Enterprise Systems Administrators for help and he diagnosed it in about 5 minutes of looking at a few screen shots I sent him.  **Problem was that the Domain Controller’s clock was set incorrectly!**  Couldn't believe it.  The servers are setup for Host Only networking so don't have internet to sync the clock with.  That also explains why rolling back to an earlier snapshot when I know the system was working didn't solve the problem.

Edit: Installing the Guest Additions on the server syncs the guest clock with the host.

Comment: I have also had AD authentication issues this year that were eventually traced back to bad clock setting on one of our Domain Controllers. I had to use Wireshark to prove to our IT dept it was a network issue, but once I got them to look... they fixed the clock and all was well.

Answer (score 3):

Another scenario where you might see this is when you are attempting to connect to another SQL server from an SSMS session that was already logged-in while you changed your password. Sequence of events might go something like:

1. RDP to Server-A (your SQL Server), open SSMS and login
2. RDP to Server-B in the same domain and change your password
3. Return to RDP session on Server-A and via SSMS attempt to add another DB into an existing AlwaysOn availability group. When connecting to replicas you get "untrusted domain"-login-error

To resolve, simply logoff and log back in

Answer (score 3):

You may be **misleaded about the username** you use locally. That was my case in Windows 10 Home. When I look at users in control panel, I see the name *usrpc01*. However when I type `net config workstation`, it appears that the user's name is *spc01*. Seems like someone renamed the user, but the internal name remained unchanged.

Not knowing how to fix windows user name (and the folder name under `C:\Users`, which also refers to the original internal name), I added a new user accout on my db server.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to log into a SQL Server 2008 from a domain account. The SQL Server 2008 is hosted on a different workgroup computer that is not part of the domain. As strange as it sounds, on the workgroup server where SQL Server 2008 is running, I had to go to System Properties | Computer Name (tab) | Change (button) | Computer Name Change | More... (button) and enter the "Primary DNS suffix of this computer" (it was blank, so enter the desired suffix for your network) and check the "Change primary DNS suffix when domain membership changes" box.  This allowed the Windows Authentication process to complete when logging into the SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use netonly to get this to work on modern Windows:

`runas /netonly /user:domain\user "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

Another reason> 
someone changed the password for the default SQL user

this happened to me a couple of minutes ago by switching to a new domain controller ...

Comment: Just happened to me. I changed my password a while back and forgot (credentials were saved)

Answer (score 1):

I had wrong entry in hosts file under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Make sure to have entry like below

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost   servername
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using an alias for an SQL Server instance that pointed to "127.0.0.1".
Changing it to "localhost" instead did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If your Sql Server is running on a server that's is not part of a domain and in the connection string you use a fully qualifed domain name (e.g. xyz.mypc.com) with Integrated Security=True, you might have to switch to using either the IP address, MachineName (SERVER01), or the dot (.) in case it's locally hosted.

This worked for me, using the fqdn resulted in the above error.

Answer (score 0):

in order to enable windows authentication both computers need to be in the same domain. in order to allow managment studios to pass the current credentials and authenticate in the sql box

Comment: This is inaccurate. They don't need to be in the same domain. They can be in different domains if an account with the same name and password is setup in both domains.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to disconnect (change workgroup/domain) from the Domain and reconnect.

Comment: Do you mean to connect using local account to remote SQL Server in workgroup? This will work only if Guest (or some other common) accounts with the same password are enabled both in SQL Server machine, connecting machine and in SQL Server itself as login.

Comment: I mean disengage then re-engage with the domain group. Then retry logging in using Windows auth (Domain credentials) on remote MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

And another possible reason: 
The new created local Account on DB Server had the: "User must change Password at next Login" Flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it for me:
Properties of network connection
Click on: "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCT/IPv4)".
Click "Properties" button.
Click "Advanced" button.
Select "DNS" tab.
Delete text in "DNS suffix for this connection".

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to remotely connect to the SQL server either. Both SQL server and remote server where in the same domain. And I had been requested a password change some days before.
Restarting both the SQL server and the remote server I was trying to access SQL server from did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was the fact that the developer was running the application pool under his own account, and had reset his password but forgot to change it on the application pool. Duh...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the server had been disabled in the domain controller. I went into the COMPUTERS OU in Active directory, right-clicked on the server,enabled it, then did a gpupdate /force from the SQL server. It took a moment, but it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in the host file, the machine name is hard coded with older IP. 
I replace the older IP with the new one, the issue is resolved.

Host file location

WindowsDrive:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Modifications done
**159.xx.xx.xxx MachineName**

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. What I had to do was:
In SQL Server Management Studio on the login screen, select Options >>
In the Network section change the Network protocol to Named Pipes.

Also, what I had to do to make it work with the `<default>` setting was to disable the wireless network (the machine was also connected to the wired lan).

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to change the web.config file to correlate with my new server name for SQL Connection (IT Security had just done a netdom rename on my development box.

Answer (score -1):

I replaced the connecting string and it started working

from

```
main_sqlconnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Master;Trusted_Connection=True")
```

to

```
main_sqlconnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Master;User ID=ARM;Password=1;")
```

I created the account `User ID=User;Password=1;` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: click on Security and add a new user.

Comment: This definitely works.  Unfortunately, it is against policy where I work.

Comment: It is also NOT using integrated authentication.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the `sa` account first and log in to your SQL management studio with the `sa` account (please chose SQl Server authentication).

After you logged in with the sa account, go to `security`, right-click on `logins`, select `new login`, select `SQL Server authentication`, create a user name (no `/` or any other special characters, just a name), then give it a password, confirm the password and at the bottom of that page select your default Database.

Go to `logins`, right-click on the user you created and click on `properties`.

Go to `Server Roles` and select the roles you want to give to the user you created.

Click `OK` and go back to `login properties`, click on `User Mapping`, double-click on the database you want to map this user to and select the database role membership for that database in the bottom window.

Comment: The OP already stated he can login with SQL authentication, so your solution would not help. He also updated the initial post and stated the issue was caused by a AD server that was down.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are are not using "Trusty_Connection=yes" somewhere. I had this same problem and I fix by simply setting this to "no".

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I wanted to run my project on another PC. Changing connection string from

```
Data Source=JOHN-PC\JJ;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False
```

to

```
Data Source=JOHN-PC\JJ;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyUserPassword
```

helped me.

This is the link where original answer is: [Login failed.The login is from an untrusted domain...](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1081462/Login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain)

Hope this would help.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove `Trusted_Connection=True` property from the connection string.

Comment: The OP clearly states the login was from an untrusted domain. Turning off "Trusted_Connection" would not do anything. Other than that, when one uses SQL Server Management Studio, you typically just enter the credentials, rather than building up a connection string.