# SQL Mixed Authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

So I have a database with mixed authentication mode. I have a piece of software that connects to it. I was using this software since about January with no problems. I add a table to this database. When I try to access this table by a query I get `Log In Failed. The log in is from an untrusted domain` This is odd because my connection string is `connectionString="Data Source=JOET-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AmazonProShip; User Id= Shipper; Password=Shipping1;` 
Has any encounter this and found a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain

Comment: @ChrisBint His question was actually pretty different than mine. Active Directory should not be an issue here since I am not using Windows to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you recently apply SQL Server updates (directly, or indirectly through Windows update)? There is a known issue where mixed mode occasionally gets changed to Windows auth only.

If you have Management Studio (and maybe Express has this functionality as well), you can check / update it by right-clicking the server name in Object Explorer, selecting Properties, moving to Security - it's the first radio option.

If you don't have Management Studio, you need to find the right LoginMode registry subkey for your instance (probably HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Microsoft SQL Server > MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS > MSSQLServer) and change the value to 2 (if it is not already 2, stop SQL Server first, change the value, close the registry, and restart SQL Server).

Comment: how would I find this in Management Studio?

Comment: Object Explorer > right-click the top level node for the instance and select Properties > check the Security tab, there is a radio button for "Server authentication" that will either be "Windows Authentication mode" or "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" - if you want to use SQL logins you will need to make sure it's set to the latter option.

Comment: I have done that before I assume you meant Windows update does some thing much deeper.

Comment: It was a bug in at least one update that affects SQL Server (there was a recent update from Windows update that did affects SQL Server, but I'm not sure if it could exhibit this specific issue).