# TFS could not connect to database. Login field

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops

I am getting the following error. Cannot solve.New to TFS. Please help.

**TF246017**: *Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.--> login failed. Login from untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication.*

Comment: check connection strings for your tfs, also can you access the db under the credentials?

Comment: I am sorry as I am working on tfs for just a couple of days, can you please tell me where to check the connection string for TFS? :(

Comment: I hope in the Web.config. But, I need to know with which user credentials, TFS is trying to log in?

Comment: could you access admin console for tfs?

Comment: Check following guide for tfs: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/11/where-do-i-find-the-tfs-2010-database.aspx

Comment: I checked the sql server logs.. it says login issue with "nam\sppinks011" as this is from untrusted domain. Now, how to change this?

Comment: if you are in larger company I would suggest to check with service helpdesk | or check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open SQL Server Manager on your TFS Server application tier using "runas" to open it under the same credentials that you expect TFS to use you should be able to diagnose more:

1) install SQL Server Manager on TFS AppTier
2) right-click on the SQL Server Manager icon and select 'run-as' ( you may need to hold alt)
3) enter the TFS Service (refer to TFS Installation Guide) credentials to open
4) try to connect to your SQL Server
If you cant connect verify that SQL is installed where you think it is and that there are no firewall issues for the standard SQL ports.

Comment: If you open the TFS Admin console you can check what connection string it is using to connect to the Data Tier, and also what service account TFS is using when it connects.

Comment: The problem occurs just after restoring the db backup of default collection database from production. I checked the config file and also connection string, no issues in that. We are not replacing the config db as well. On restoring the defaultcollection db, we start getting this issue. :(