# Node.JS can't connect a local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm trying to pass my windows domain credentials to a **LOCAL** SQL Server and I'm getting this weird error:

```
Could not connect to sql:  { [ConnectionError: Login failed. The login is from a
n untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.]
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be us
ed with Windows authentication.',
  code: 'ELOGIN' }
```

I also tried connecting to a remote SQL Server without success.

When I pass SQL Authentication it works fine

Here's the code:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var conn_str = { 

        server: 'ccc',
        database: 'TEST',
        domain: 'Name',
        user: 'xxxxx',
        password: 'xx',

        options : {
        trustedConnection : true
         }
}


var connection = new sql.Connection(conn_str, function(err) {
    // ... error checks
    if(err) {
    return console.log("Could not connect to sql: ", err);
    }

    // Query

    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query('select top 10 * from xxxx (nolock)', function(err,recordset) {
        // ... error checks

        console.dir(recordset);
    });

    // Stored Procedure


});
```

Comment: you are probably missing a certificate for Kerberos authentication

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Windows Auth Login Error: The login is from an untrusted domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain)

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried [this](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/338), it didn't work for me but maybe it'll work for other people.