# .net SQL authentication issue

Tags: c#, sql-server

My setup

I have a winform application that connects to a `local sql express db` and does different operations `(updates,inserts,deletes)`
The sql express is local and i am using the following connection string (from app.config)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=database1;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <!--<add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

My application is first authenticating the user when it logs on (via the database1...so it can connect to the DB)
I am also able to connect to the SQL management console without any issues. I see and able to change the tables from within the DB via the management console
I am getting the **"The Login is from an Untrusted Domain and Cannot be used with Windows Authentication"** when I am trying to do operations on the different tables
I have also tried to use the server name instead of the "." in the connection string to no avail.
In my application i am referencing the app.config file to get the connectionStrings

Comment: `Danny G` take a look at this link it will show many examples on how to connect to Sql Server via C# [ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com) here is a [MSDN Sql Server Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx) link as well

Comment: The problem is not connecting via the connection string. As i mentioned my app is authenticating the users via a log on screen against the DB. That part is working just fine.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain  Or this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332

Comment: change your connection string to the following 
`<add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=database1;Integrated Security=true"` if you are passing user name and password then Security =false would be the setting I just tried the suggestion without `SSPI` and it worked for me failed when I added it back..

Comment: Danny, can you please add appropriate periods to those sentences as some of them blend together and make it hard to understand. Are you saying that your webapp can connect and select data successfully for the login form? When exactly do you see the "The Login..." error? In your app?

Comment: Correct. The first thing my application is doing is authenticating the user against my DB. That is working as expected. Once the user logs on it will do different actions such as selects,updates,inserts against the DB. This is where the problems start.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that ASP.NET is still set to the default of not passing along a security context. You should enable [ASP.NET Impersonation Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708.aspx) by running the following from a command prompt:

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:identity /impersonate:true
```

As far as the connection string goes, it should be fine. The difference between `SSPI` and `True` for the [Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752.aspx#integratedsecurity) option is:

- **SSPI** (Security Support Provider Interface) means use Windows Security if **User ID** and **Password** are absent, and use SQL Server security if they are present.
- **True** means use Windows integrated security to log in to SQL Server, even if the connection string includes **User ID** and **Password** settings.

Since you are not specifying **User ID** and **Password** in your connection string, the **SSPI** and **True** values should effectively be the same.

Other areas to check if the above doesn't work:

- The authentication account of the IIS service
- The local security policy (based on the "The Login is from an Untrusted Domain" part).