# Sharepoint 2010: Central Admin connection failing with - The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Our setup: 
Server1: Sharepoint is running
Server2: SQL Server is running

Our Sharepoint 2010 was working perfectly fine and then suddenly the website went down and when I tried accessing Central Admin I found the following issue in the error log:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

I read on internet that this happens when the server loses trust with the domain so I removed the Sharepoint server from the domain and then added it back. Result: Same. No solution.

I also tried other methods where people have asked for updating the host file but that too did not work.

**In order to check if the connection is working or not...i did UDL test where I created a file networkcheck.udl on Sharepoint server machine (Server1) and tried running with Windows authentication and tried to connect with DB server (Server2).

*Result: Connection successful.***

Can anyone please guide regarding this. I don't know why Sharepoint won't connect even after udl test being successful.

Comment: Looks like you've made sure the servers are communicating correctly, Have you gone down to the database level yet, I'm assuming that using the same credentials you can log in to SQL studio and see all the SP Databases?

Comment: @Trueplaya: Yes, I have logged onto the Database server and have access to all the SP Databases there. I wanted to remove the database server from the domain and add it again, but could not do it because this database server hosts other website databases too. We cannot risk that.

Comment: What service pack is installed?  And, do you use multiple service accounts for your environment or only one.  If you use multiple, check that the passwords haven't expired for all service accounts.

Comment: You might have to configure [Kerberos and SPN](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62174/planning-for-spns-what-spns-would-i-need)...

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know enough about your farm as a whole you may be best looking at this as a issue unrelated to SharePoint.

Are bother the servers in the same domain?

Like Dennis said have any of the passwords Expired/Changed?

Do you have anything other than localhost pointing to 127.0.0.1 in your Hosts file?

Check this thread and think of the problem away from SharePoint

[SQL Server 2008 Windows Auth Login Error: The login is from an untrusted domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain)

Thanks 
Truez

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities of this error could be that the account from which the Server has been installed has been removed from the domain or the account password has been changed.