# Connecting to SQL database over Windows Remote Desktop: The Login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with WIndows Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am connecting to an SQL database thus:

```
using (sqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = a.b.c.d;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true"))
{
    connection.Open();
```

The server pointed to by a.b.c.d is a remote server.

When I run this code from my laptop it works just fine - the connection is made.

If, however, I connect to server a.b.c.d via Windows Remote Desktop using my Windows login, and then run the same code locally on a.b.c.d I get an exception thrown from

```
connection.Open();
```

The exception is

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication.
```

I don't get it - aren't I logging in using the same credentials?  Why the exception?

Comment: See if the router on the server supports loopback function

Comment: Then try to connect locally using LAN IP

Comment: If it's ok, I suppose the problem is with your router not the code nor the server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain

Comment: @f855a864 Using the LAN IP worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server= server ip ;Database=Db.name;User Id= ur_id;Password=ur_ps;Trusted_Connection=false");
```

Server ip should be your remote desktop's LAN ip or WAN ip.