# Cannot connect to local SQL Server 2012 via SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server 2012 via SSMS, but I didn't make it. I got error message :

> Cannot connect to EB-OR1007724.
>
> **Additional information:**
>   Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

Please notice that I'm using a company computer with many restrictions. After trying several things, but I stilled didn't make it.

**Check services are running**. All related SQL Server Services are running using `Local System` as Log On. They're

- SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER), started (PID=2100)
- SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER), started (PID=2424)
- SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER), started (PID=320)
- SQL Server Browser, started (PID=4376)

**Check ports' status**. The port `:1434` is listened by localhost `127.0.0.1`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\xxxxxxxx>netstat -ano
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  ...
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1434         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2424
  TCP    [::1]:1434             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2424
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1434           *:*                                    3080                                1016
  UDP    [::]:1434              *:*                                    3080
```

**Check firewall roles**. I've created an inbound rule to allow TCP connection to port `:1433` and `:1434`, which can be accessed for all connections by anyone.

**Check hosts config**. The hosts configuration file `hosts` has been modified to identified 127.0.0.1 as localhost. This file is located at folder `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

**Check availability of other SQL Server services**. I can connect to the local SSAS services using my windows authentication.

[image: Local services]

**Check AD Server status**. The problem might be caused by a down Active Directory Server. Even though I don't have access to `Active Directory Domains and trusts` due to company policy, I'm sure that the AD server works, because I can connect to the local SSAS services using my windows authentication.

**Check instance name**. As you can see, the instance is called `MSSQLSERVER`, so perhaps I should explicitly mention it when I connect via SSMS ? These are what I've tried in `Server name`:

- `EB-OR1007724`, error 18452
- `EB-OR1007724\`, error 18452
- `EB-OR1007724\MSSQLSERVER`, error 87
- `.\MSSQLSERVER`, error 87
- `.\`, error 18452
- `.`, error 18452

Now I'm really upset upon the result. Please help T_T

---

### Error list

**Error 87**

> Cannot connect to EB-OR1007724\MSSQLSERVER.
>   **Additional Information:**
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)
>   The parameter is incorrect.

**Error 18452**

> Cannot connect to EB-OR1007724.
>
> **Additional information:**
>   Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

For your information, there's a related question [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain).

Comment: I could connect to DB Engine this morning but I couldn't this afternoon. Now when I restart the computer, the connection works again... Why ??

Comment: looks like there maybe problems with your computer OS? antivirus? I can't think of any reason you will have problem connecting to you your own local SQL engine.. it is weird.

Comment: Unlees you've installed the database as a named instance, there is no reason to use an instance name to connect to the default instance. Just `.` is enough. On the other hand, the error complains about the *user credentials*, ie. it doesn't like your account. Did you try to login with a local account, even though your machine is part of a domain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Cause**

The problem might be caused by company security programs, defined on the network. Since the local service `MSSQLSERVER` is not a company official service, the Active Directory (AD) Server refuses to provide authentication credentials. (Obviously, this is my hypothesis. ^^)

**Solution**

As for the solution, I use **SQL Server Authentication** instead of Windows Authentication to login. In order to do that, make sure your server is running under the `Mixed Mode` (Windows authentication and SQL Server authentication). This can be configured during the SQL Server 2012 installation, step **Database Engine Configuration**.

[image: Set up during installation]

The login is **sa** (system administrator) and the password is what you've defined previously.

[image: Connect to Server (SSMS)]

**Once connected, you should add new login(s)** properly for different usages. As mentioned by Panagiotis Kanavos:

> connecting as `sa` is considered a serious security problem, not a solution of any kind. It should never, ever be attempted in production systems

Comment: Disabling Windows Authentication *and connecting as `sa`* is considered a serious security problem, not a solution of any kind. It should never, ever be attempted in production systems

Comment: I agree with you. Please let me know what can I do to solve this problem properly. I still can't connect to my localhost using my windows authentication.

Comment: Is your machine part of a domain? Did you try to log in using a local account? The error is rather clear - the server doesn't trust your account.

Comment: My machine is part of the domain and I always tried with my local account. The most strange thing is, I can connection to SSAS using this account. I've mentionned in the question > Check AD Server status.

Comment: For your information, we've another machine in production. I can connect to its db engine remotely using my account via SSMS