# How to connect to Remote MS SQL Database using Windows Authentication of Remote Desktop in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, remote-desktop, jtds

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL database from my machine using Java.

Generally, I login to a remote desktop and connect to the database using Windows Authentication of the remote desktop.

I tried using JTDS

```
  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<database server>;"
        + "user=<domain>\<username>;password=<password>"
```

But that returned with login failure error. 
      *"java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'domain\username'."*

Comment: Windows Authentication means you *don't* specify a name. The application connects with the account of the current user.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "using Windows Authentication of the remote desktop", I'm pretty sure remote desktop by default uses your windows credentials. By adding

```
integratedSecurity=true;
```

and removing

```
"user=<domain>\<username>;password=<password>"
```

you force java to use your integrated (Windows Authentication) credentials to log into the database like you would "generally"

NOTE
this will only work if  you are accessing the database from the normal COMPUTER and USER that you would "Generally" use to log in to remote desktop

So in conclusion:

```
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<database server>;integratedSecurity=true;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<Server name>:<Port Number>;databaseName=<Database Name>;domain=<Domain Name>;useNTLMv2=True;user=<Domain Account Name>;password=<Domain Account password>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I'm getting this message. Login failed. 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Upon searching for this, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain

Here the top answer says "For me, this happened when I edited a blank drivers/etc/hosts file, and added an entry for a local website, but neglected to add 127.0.0.1 localhost"

Do you know which system I do this on? Remote or my local?

Comment: Probably check domain server connectivity from this server.

Comment: Windows Authentication means that you *don't* supply any username. The application connects with the logged-in user's account. That means that you *don't* have to store the credentials anywhere, passwords can change without affecting applications and you don't have to worry about people stealing the username and password.

Comment: Furthermore, NTLM v2 is obsolete. It was introduce with NT 4 SP4 back in 2000 and disabled in almost all domains. What this connection string tries to do is connect by *impersonating* the specified user (which requires administrator privileges), using a weak and deprecated protocol

Comment: Do you have reference of this claim "NTLMV2 is obsolete"?