# PHP PDO Cannot Connecto MSQL - . The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am attempting to test and debug an application on my development machine that contacts a database on another machine.

I am receiving the following error:

```
Database connection failure: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

My "connect" function looks like this:

```
    private function connect() {
    try {
        $conString = "sqlsrv:Server=$this->host;Database=$this->db, $this->user, $this->pass";
        $conn = new PDO ( $conString );
        $conn->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo "Database connection failure: " . $e->getMessage ();
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

with "$conString" having the form of:

```
sqlsrv:Server=XX.XX.XX.XX;Database=myDB, USER, PASS
```

when it tries to connect.

While the error may seem straightforward, I am not sure why I am receiving it given the following:

- Both SQL server and Windows authentication are enabled on the server.
- I can connect to the same server just fine from either SQL Management Studio and ASP.NET projects using the same machine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: check credentials

Comment: Thanks, I just checked them and all appears correct.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain