# Perl dbi:Sybase Connect to SQL Server that uses Windows Authentication from linux machine

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I'm using perl DBI to connect to a SQL Server with dbi:Sybase from linux machine, but when I try to connect, it's giving me error like

`DBI connect('DBName','DOMAIN\UserName',...) failed: Server message number=18452 severity=14 state=1 line=1 server=SERVERNAME text=Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. OpenClient message: LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (34)
Server DATAMART, database
Message String: Adaptive Server connection failed
 at connect.pl line 37`

My code is:

```
BEGIN{
   $ENV{SYBASE} = "/opt/sybclient-12.5.1";
   $ENV{FREETDSCONF} = "PATH/config/freetds.conf";
}

use lib "PATH/perl-lib/lib64/perl5";
use lib "PATH/perl-lib/share/perl5/";


my $lib = "PATH/FreeTDS_32bit/libct.so.4.0.0";
DynaLoader::dl_load_file($lib, 1) or die "Unable to load freetds libct.so: $!\n";

$host = 'ServerName';  $port = 'PORT';
$database = 'DBName';  $user = 'DOMAIN\\userName'; 
$auth = 'PASS';

$_dmDBH = DBI->connect(dbi:Sybase:server=$host; database=$database;port=$port","$user", "$auth") || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

Comment: Well, this seems fun: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain

Comment: Can  you confirm whether you're trying to connect to a MS SQL Server or  Sybase instance running on Windows as 'SQL Server' can be taken for either RDBMS.

Comment: @ Rich Campbell  I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this with freeTds, In freeTds config file we need to set ntlmv2 to yes

```
[PACKAGE-NAME]
        host = <HOSTANME>
        database = <DB-Name>
        tds version = 8.0
        use ntlmv2 = yes
        client charset = UTF-8
```